# mysql query showing error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, moodle, find-in-set

Mysql query,

```
SELECT qcat.name,
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "todo" THEN 1 END ) AS gtotal,
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "gradedright" THEN 1 END ) AS rightanswer, 
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "gradedwrong" THEN 1 END ) AS wronganswer, 
SUM(qas.fraction) AS grade,
quiza.id 
FROM mdl_quiz_attempts quiza
JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.questionusageid = quiza.uniqueid 
JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps qas ON qas.questionattemptid = qa.id 
JOIN mdl_question qstn ON ( qa.`questionid` = qstn.id ) 
JOIN mdl_question_categories qcat ON ( qstn.`category` = qcat.id ) 
WHERE quiza.id=1173 and FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, (1,2,3,4,5,6)) GROUP BY quiza.id,qcat.name
```

showing error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Try replace `FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, (1,2,3,4,5,6))` with `FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, 1,2,3,4,5,6)` (remove parenthesis)

Comment: not work showing , #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET' error

Comment: My bad, Try replace `FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, (1,2,3,4,5,6))` with `FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, '1,2,3,4,5,6')` (list as string)

Comment: no error but null output..thanks

Comment: Well, there is where your error occurs. Now you need to write a query that return data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT qcat.name,
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "todo" THEN 1 END ) AS gtotal,
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "gradedright" THEN 1 END ) AS rightanswer, 
COUNT( CASE WHEN qas.state = "gradedwrong" THEN 1 END ) AS wronganswer, 
SUM(qas.fraction) AS grade,
quiza.id 
FROM mdl_quiz_attempts quiza
JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.questionusageid = quiza.uniqueid 
JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps qas ON qas.questionattemptid = qa.id 
JOIN mdl_question qstn ON ( qa.`questionid` = qstn.id ) 
JOIN mdl_question_categories qcat ON ( qstn.`category` = qcat.id ) 
WHERE quiza.id=1173 and FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, "1,2,3,4,5,6") GROUP BY quiza.id,qcat.name
```

Comment: Ithink you missed the position of the string like,  " WHERE quiza.id=1173 and @@position_of_string =  FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, "1,2,3,4,5,6")"

Comment: WHERE quiza.id=1173 and 1 = FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, "1,2,3,4,5,6") GROUP BY quiza.id,qcat.name

Comment: execute the query by removing the "and FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, "1,2,3,4,5,6")" in where clause and check are you getting any data or not

Comment: @jatin-grover This answer appears to answer your specific question about the error.

To continue troubleshooting. Try removing your filter context the `WHERE ...` statement and validate the results you expect exist.  If not, you need to review your join statements.  If they do exist try editing your where statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
FIND_IN_SET(qstn.id, (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

It should be:

```
qstn.id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

or:

```
qstn.id BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

`FIND_IN_SET()` is used when the list of values is in a comma-separated string, `IN` is used with a literal list in the query.